# Remove Trailing Slash From Batch File Input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, substring

I have a batch file that I want to improve. Instead of requiring a user to provide a folder path without a trailing slash, is there an easy way for me to just remove the last character from the path if there is a slash on the end?

```
:START
@echo What folder do you want to process? (Provide a path without a closing backslash)
set /p datapath=

::Is string empty?
IF X%datapath% == X GOTO:START

::Does string have a trailing slash?
IF %datapath:~-1%==\ GOTO:START
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

you can use syntax similar your evaluation:

```
::Does string have a trailing slash? if so remove it 
IF %datapath:~-1%==\ SET datapath=%datapath:~0,-1%
```

Comment: Thanks! I just ran into such an issue, and this was the perfect answer.

Comment: You can also consider just adding a `.` in the case of a trailing slash. A lil' shorter than the substring syntax.

Comment: What if the path was `"C:\My Folder\"` ?

Comment: Conversely, if you want to ensure that there IS a backslash on the end, it would be: ```IF NOT "%datapath:~-1%"=="\" SET "datapath=%datapath%\"``` to force it.  The quotes protect internal spaces.

Comment: If there are spaces in the path then you need to be careful with quotes. If `%datapath%` contains leading and trailing quotes then you can use `IF "%datapath:~-2,-1%"=="\" SET datapath="%datapath:~1,-2%"`

Comment: Worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853380/1540350 <- This also works for arguments