# How to get the path of a batch script without the trailing backslash in a single command?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Suppose I wish to get the absolute path of a batch script from within the batch script itself, but without a trailing backslash. Normally, I do it this way:

```
SET BuildDir=%~dp0
SET BuildDir=%BuildDir:~0,-1%
```

The first statement gets the path with the trailing backslash and the second line removes the last character, i.e. the backslash. Is there a way to combine these two statements into a single line of code?

Answer (score 54):

Instead of removing the trailing backslash, adding a trailing dot is semantically equivalent for many software.

C:\Windows **is equivalent to** C:\Windows\.

```
echo %dp0
>C:\Windows\

echo %dp0.
>C:\Windows\.
```

#### For example, robocopy accepts only directories without trailing spaces.

This errors out:

```
robocopy "C:\myDir" %~dp0
```

This is successful:

```
robocopy "C:\myDir" %~dp0.
```

Comment: While it's certainly useful for that particular robocopy use-case, it's not what OP asked for.

Comment: `C:\Windows\.notepad.exe` is not equivalent to `C:\Windows\notepad.exe`

Answer (score 6):

Only with delayed expansion when you write both statements into the same line:

```
set BuildDir=%~dp0&&set BuildDir=!BuildDir:~0,-1!
```

But that kinda defies the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the modifiers ability of the FOR variables.

```
for %%Q in ("%~dp0\.") DO set "BuildDir=%%~fQ"
```

The `%%~fQ` results to the required path without trailing backslash (nor `\.`)

And this creates still a valid absolute path for the case, when the batch file is in a root directory on any drive.

This solution returns `D:\`, instead of `D:` only by simply removing the trailing 
character.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that it is not safe to use the substring tricks on variables that contain file system paths, there are just too many symbols like !,^,% that are valid folder/file names and there is no way to properly escape them all

FOR /D seems to strip the trailing backslash, so here is a version that uses for:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion&set _CD=%CD%&cd /D "%~dp0"&(FOR /D %%a IN ("!CD!") DO ((cd /D !_CD!)&endlocal&set "BuildDir=%%~a"))
```

This requires Win2000 and will probably fail if the batch file is on a UNC path

Comment: Do you have any examples of where substring operations fail on paths?

Comment: @emddudley: I don't know a substring example off the top of my head, but when dealing with variables you have to remember that "foo!OS!bar%PROMPT%baz" is a valid filename ;)

Answer (score -1):

Example script "c:\Temp\test.cmd":

```
@set BuildDir=%~dp0.
@echo Build directory: "%BuildDir%"
```

Run in console:

```
d:\> cmd /C c:\Temp\test.cmd
Build directory: "c:\Temp\."
```

Comment: While neat, it's not what OP asked for. Adding a '.' is not the same as removing the trailing slash.

Comment: could you please clarify you point? OP asked "I wish to get the absolute path without a trailing backslash". Not canonical (without backslash or dot), not relative (your example), but absolute path with one-liner

Comment: The output of the single-line command should be `C:\Temp`, not `C:\Temp\ ` or `C:\Temp\.`. I'm just saying that adding is not the same as removing, even if they evaluate to the same thing later.

Comment: you are right - these are different ways. but how this relates to OP question? "The output ... should be C:\Temp" - why?? Canonical and absolute paths are not the same thing

Comment: The output should be "C:\Temp" because OP asked for the trailing slash to be removed. That's literally the only requirement.

Comment: Looks like this was you, who did not read the question. "How to get the path of a batch script without the trailing backslash in a single command" is not the same as "How to remove trailing backslash in a single command". No more questions. And thanks for your answers.

Comment: @tzrlk, I agree with ursa here. The literal question is "_How to get the path of a batch script without the trailing backslash (...)_", not how to _remove_ the trailing backslash, even though that was the solution OP did attempt to achieve. This answer offers a valid solution to the question. NB: It's a bit strange that another answer posted a month later with the same solution got 52 upvotes (although admittently that answer contains a bit more details/explanation).

Answer (score -3):

The simplest solution that worked for me was

**Instead of using** : `SET currentPath=%~dp0`

**USE** : `SET currentPath=%cd%`

Comment: `%cd%` points to the current working directory, that can or can not be the path of the batch script, which can be obtained from `%~dp0`

Comment: This is actually the best solution, although incomplete. It's a bit more work, but we can move into the script directory (temporarily) to set up the path using %cd%, through `pushd %~dp0`, `echo %cd%`, `popd`.

Comment: if you run the batch file `c:\test\test2\script.bat`  from command prompt by going to some intermediate folder like `c:\test` then the %cd% will return `C:\test:` instead of the script path which is always the zeroth parameter, which you can expand as file name with `%~f0` or directory path `%~dp0` . `%cd%` just return the directory where command is triggered