# WMIC: how to use "process call create" with the current working directory

Tags: windows, wmic

I want to use `wmic Process call create` to open a CMD at current working directory. But when I add `"%~dp0"` to specify directory the following command output nothing.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==; " %%I in ('wmic Process call create "cmd.exe"^,"%~dp0" ^| find "ProcessId"') do echo PID = %%I
```

As I know `%~dp0` will end with `\`, so `%~dp0` will be like `C:\Users\`.

If I remove `\` It will works. E.g: The following command will work.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==; " %%I in ('wmic Process call create "cmd.exe"^,"C:\Users" ^| find "ProcessId"') do echo PID = %%I
```

How can I use `wmic Process call create` with dynamic working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to add a trailing dot (`.`).

`%~dp0` to `%~dp0.`

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==; " %%I in ('wmic Process call create "cmd.exe"^,"%~dp0." ^| find "ProcessId"') do echo PID = %%I
```

Read more: [How to get the path of a batch script without the trailing backslash in a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160058/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-batch-script-without-the-trailing-backslash-in-a-single)