# Handling trailing backslash & directory names with spaces in batch files

Tags: batch-file

This is a variation of this question:
[Remove Trailing Slash From Batch File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952401/remove-trailing-slash-from-batch-file-input)

but it's subtly different, so I don't think it's a dupe.

I'm having trouble making this work with directories that have spaces in them (running WinXP).

```
:START
@echo What folder do you want to process? (Provide a path without a closing backslash)
set /p datapath=

::Is string empty?
IF X%datapath% == X GOTO:START

::Does string have a trailing slash? if so remove it 
IF %datapath:~-1%==\ SET datapath=%datapath:~0,-1%

echo %datapath%
```

It handles:

```
c:\
```

properly (stripping it to c:)

But if you enter:

```
c:\test space
```

the error is "space was unexpected at this time."

If you try enter:

```
"c:\test space"
```

You get the same error.

I thought it would involve a strategically placed " or two in this line:

```
IF %datapath:~-1%==\ SET datapath=%datapath:~0,-1%
```

But I haven't had any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with delayed expansion, because delayed expansion works different than percent expansion.

```
:START
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo What folder do you want to process? (Provide a path without a closing backslash)
set /p datapath=

::Is string empty?
IF X!datapath! == X GOTO:START

::Does string have a trailing slash? if so remove it 
IF !datapath:~-1!==\ SET "datapath=!datapath:~0,-1!"

echo !datapath!
```

It expands later than the *percent* expansion, and after the delayed expansion no more parsing is done, so even spaces or special characters have any effect.