# Using SetDelayedExpansion in batch files: handling dirs/filenames containing !

Tags: batch-file

I have two batch files (XP):

test.bat:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem check for argument
if [%1]==[] goto :noarg

:arg
rem check for trailing backslash and remove it if it's there
set dirname=%1
IF !dirname:~-1!==\ SET "dirname=!dirname:~0,-1!"

rem find all log files in passed directory and call test2.bat for each one
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir !dirname!\*.log /s /b') do call test2.bat "%%a"

goto :finish

:noarg
rem prompt for directory to scan
set /p dirname=Type the drive or directory, then hit enter: 

rem loop if nothing entered
if [!dirname!]==[] goto :noarg

rem check for trailing backslash and remove it if it's there
IF !dirname:~-1!==\ SET "dirname=!dirname:~0,-1!"

rem find all log files in passed directory and call test2.bat for each one
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir "!dirname!"\*.log /s /b') do call test2.bat "%%a"

goto :finish

:finish
```

test2.bat:

```
echo %1
```

Demonstrating the problem:

-Create a directory called c:\test and another called c:\test! and put an empty test.log file in each directory.

Then run:

```
test c:\test
```

This works as expected (test2.bat echoes "c:\test\test.log")

Now run:

```
test c:\test!
```

The problem is that test2.bat echoes "c:\test\test.log" instead of the desired "c:\test!\test.log")

I realize this is because ! is reserved for EnableDelayedExpansion use.  But if the solution is "use % expansion", then I'm hung because I need to use DelayedExpansion (per [Handling trailing backslash & directory names with spaces in batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197765/handling-trailing-backslash-directory-names-with-spaces-in-batch-files) )

I've poked around with:

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

and

```
endlocal
```

and [How can I escape an exclamation mark ! in cmd scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288552/how-can-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark-in-cmd-scripts)

with no luck (could be PEBCAK).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are the expansions of %1 and %%a, with delayed expansion the ! is removed.
So you should first disable the delayed expansion.
Btw. Removing the trailing slash is not neccessary (EDIT: only true, if it is not a root path)

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem check for argument
if "%~1"=="" goto :noarg

:arg
set "dirname=%~1"

rem find all log files in passed directory and call test2.bat for each one
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir "%dirname%\*.log" /s /b') do (
  set "file=%%~a"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo found #!file!#
  call test2.bat "!file!"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: Thanks again @jeb! Just when I think I'm getting my head around something...

Would you mind explaining why I don't need to remove trailing backslashes?  I'm doing it to handle, for example, a user passing c:\ - which makes the for /F line error out because of: `"c:\\*.log"`

Comment: @Craig H: You are right, it doesn't work with the root dir, but in any other like c:\temp\\*.log (I only test the second case)

Comment: thanks for the clarification - just wanted to see if I was overlooking something.  Thanks once again for your help!