# Open Cygwin on a path passed as the first parameter to bash.exe

Tags: batch-file, cygwin, console2, cygpath

I'm going mad trying to achieve this. I read a lot of questions over Stack Overflow, but they didn't work. I'm trying to open a tab on console2 that opens Cygwin on the path passed as a parameter to it.

For cmd.exe, is quite easy:

```
cmd.exe %1
```

For Cygwin, this looks really hard:

```
bash --login -i -c 'cd `cygpath \'D:\Program Files\'`;exec bash'
```

The problem here is that with path without spaces it works well, with spaces, it doesn't work. Also, I don't know how to pass a param to it, maybe $1 or %1?

**Edit 1:**

I'm *almost* there, I created this batch file that should be run instead of bash.exe directly:

```
@echo off

set CHERE_INVOKES=%CD%
set TORUN="D:\Program Files\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -c 'cd "%CHERE_INVOKES%"; exec bash'
echo %TORUN%
call %TORUN%
PAUSE
```

This works with all paths except C: (and D:), the reason? Windows is stupid, and instead of having a path called C:, it has a path called C:!!! So, while all paths ends **without a backslash**, the first path ends with it, driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
@echo off

set CHERE_INVOKES=%CD%
::Remove trailing slash if required
IF %CHERE_INVOKES:~-1%==\ SET CHERE_INVOKES=%CHERE_INVOKES:~0,-1%

set TORUN="D:\Program Files\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -c 'cd "%CHERE_INVOKES%"; exec bash'

call %TORUN%
```

I added this code from this question: [Remove Trailing Slash From Batch File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952401/remove-trailing-slash-from-batch-file-input)

```
::Remove trailing slash if required
IF %CHERE_INVOKES:~-1%==\ SET CHERE_INVOKES=%CHERE_INVOKES:~0,-1%
```

In this way I can use this batch file to open Console2 Cygwin on the current path.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i -c "cd '%~1'; exec /bin/bash.exe"
```

Where `%~1` expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (") — see `help for` in command prompt.

See also: **chere** package in Cygwin, and **ConEmu** terminal :)